# Return result only if multiple strings exist in a file

Tags: linux, pattern-matching

Is there a Linux utility which will return the name of a file only if it contains multiple specified strings?  Not necessarily on the same line.  Obviously grep can "OR" but I'm looking for "AND".

Answer (score 1):

For simple things you can use `grep` or `awk`, for more complex things you will need a programming language. Probabely the best is start with a scripting language like: python, perl, php, javascript.

The `grep` command can be used for OR:

```
ls|egrep 'first_pattern|second_pattern"
```

Or to match both patterns:

```
ls|egrep "first_pattern.*second_pattern|second_pattern.*first_pattern"
```

To understand better how to write RegEx patterns, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Really complex parsers can be written with a parser generator like [ANTLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANTLR)

Comment: The "Or to..." solution was exactly what I was looking for although I'm not sure I understood it at first.  When I looked recently I realized the significance of the '.*' meaning any number of other characters.